# The target-entity cannot be found in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using symfony and i cannot solve this problem

The target-entity Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Groups cannot be found in 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User#group'

A simplification of my entities is:

**User.php**

```
 namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="isActive", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    private $groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
    }






    // ...

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->groups->toArray();
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
      public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Add groups
     *
     * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups
     * @return User
     */
    public function addGroup(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups)
    {
        $this->groups[] = $groups;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove groups
     *
     * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups
     */
    public function removeGroup(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups)
    {
        $this->groups->removeElement($groups);
    }

    /**
     * Get groups
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getGroups()
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }
}
```

**Group.php**

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="groups")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Group implements RoleInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30) */
    private $name;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true) */
    private $role;

    /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups") */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ... getters and setters for each property

    /** @see RoleInterface */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Group
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return Group
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add users
     *
     * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $users
     * @return Group
     */
    public function addUser(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users[] = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove users
     *
     * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $users
     */
    public function removeUser(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($users);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is this code that you have here exact? The error suggests that in your user entity, the `$groups` property is actually named `$group` and the target entity is actually named `Groups`.  If the code you pasted is exact, then the error does not make sense unless you are not using annotations to define the relationships.  Could you possibly be using yml? I've done that before, I thought I was using annotations but nothing would work.  it turned out I was actually using yml instead.

Comment: this is the same code, all annotations was generated. So i should do whole entity in yml ? could You be more specific because im starting with frameworks/symfony etc.

Comment: if the code was generated, then it probably also generated the yml configurations.  What I am saying is that your annotations may not be used right now, and instead Symfony is using the generated yml files for the mappings.  look in your `Resources/config/doctrine` directory and see if the yml files are there.

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135581/doctrine-mapping-in-symfony2-using-yaml?rq=1) for how to tell what mapping type your application may be using by default.  So if you want to continue to use annotations, you must either explicitly tell Symfony that in config.yml, or ensure that no other configs (like yml) are present in your application.

Comment: yml files was generated, but i dont know why there was `code  manyToMany:
        group:
            targetEntity: Groups`  im fixed it and everything working now,thank You for help

Answer (score -1):

This is an example:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
*/
protected $products;

...

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $category;
```

You forgot the **`@ORM\JoinColumn`** annotation

Comment: you are talking about a oneToMany relationship, the question is in regards to a ManyToMany relationship. It's quite different